# ruby reading files from S3 with open-URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, id3, open-uri, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having some problems reading a file from S3.  I want to be able to load the ID3 tags remotely, but using open-URI doesn't work, it gives me the following error:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > c=TagLib2::File.new(open(URI.parse("http://recordtemple.com.s3.amazonaws.com/music/745/original/The%20Stranger.mp3?1292096514")))
TypeError: can't convert Tempfile into String
    from (irb):8:in `initialize'
    from (irb):8:in `new'
    from (irb):8
```

However, if i download the same file and put it on my desktop (ie no need for open-URI), it works just fine.

```
c=TagLib2::File.new("/Users/momofwombie/Desktop/blah.mp3")
```

is there something else I should be doing to read a remote file?

UPDATE:  I just found this link, which may explain a little bit, but surely there must be some way to do this...

[Read header data from files on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640354/read-header-data-from-files-on-remote-server)

Answer (score 4):

Might want to check out [AWS::S3](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/), a Ruby Library for Amazon's Simple Storage Service

Do an `AWS::S3:S3Object.find` for the file and then an use `about` to retrieve the metadata

This solution assumes you have the AWS credentials and permission to access the S3 bucket that contains the files in question.

Comment: that would work, except my metadata appears to be blank.  do you have to supply your own metadata with s3?  this would be perfect as I wouldn't have to download it.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

`TagLib2::File.new` doesn't take a file handle, which is what you are passing to it when you use `open` without a `read`.

Add on `read` and you'll get the contents of the URL, but `TagLib2::File` doesn't know what to do with that either, so you are forced to read the contents of the URL, and save it.

I also noticed you are unnecessarily complicating your use of OpenURI. You don't have to parse the URL using `URI` before passing it to `open`. Just pass the URL string.

```
require 'open-uri'

fname = File.basename($0) << '.' << $$.to_s
File.open(fname, 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.print open("http://recordtemple.com.s3.amazonaws.com/music/745/original/The%20Stranger.mp3?1292096514").read
end

c = TagLib2::File.new(fname)

# do more processing...

File.delete(fname)
```

I don't have TagLib2 installed but I ran the rest of the code and the mp3 file downloaded to my disk and is playable. The `File.delete` would clean up afterwards, which should put you in the state you want to be in.

Answer (score 2):

This solution isn't going to work much longer. Paperclip > 3.0.0 has removed to_file. I'm using S3 & Heroku. What I ended up doing was copying the file to a temporary location and parsing it from there. Here is my code:

```
dest = Tempfile.new(upload.spreadsheet_file_name)
dest.binmode
upload.spreadsheet.copy_to_local_file(:default_style, dest.path)
file_loc = dest.path 

...

CSV.foreach(file_loc, :headers => true, :skip_blanks => true) do |row|}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work instead of open-URI:

```
Mp3Info.open(mp3.to_file.path) do |mp3info|
  puts mp3info.tag.artist
end
```

Paperclip has a to_file method that downloads the file from S3.