# Ruby redirect STDOUT to AWS S3Object

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

Is there a way in Ruby to redirect `STDOUT` to an `S3Object`? I would like my `puts` output to write to my `S3Object`. I can do `stdout.reopen` but need a filename.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987362/how-can-i-capture-stdout-to-a-string

Comment: look at @fearless_fool's answer.

Comment: Interesting. So I guess I could buffer all my output to a string that way, and finally write it to S3. I was hoping to write it as I went along so each puts writes incrementally and progress can be monitored. Also to reduce memory buffering size. But this can work for my situation where output isn't enormous, thanks.

Comment: you can also do that if you want :) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801731/rails-how-to-send-file-from-s3-to-remote-server/32833143#32833143 the idea is to use a pipe. attach the write side to the STDOUT and read from reader side :) this way you are actually streaming to S3